# How can I rewrite the cart.php to cart using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website where I'm using cart.php to add items / show items into the cart. When someone add item into the cart the URL of the cart page is www.domain.com/cart/0. After adding the product the cart page URL is www.domain.com/cart.php. I need to rewrite the cart page URL as www.domain.com/cart.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help

write this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^abc/index  index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^abc/about  about.php [L]
RewriteRule ^abc/services  services.php [L]
RewriteRule ^abc/rates  rates.php [L]
RewriteRule ^abc/contact#main  contact#main.php [L]
```

Now you hide your extension. For more details visit: [rewrite urls](http://www.phponwebsites.com/2013/11/how-to-redirect-urls-using-htaccess.html)